# Aggregation error: $arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array, but is object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to aggregate a collection in mongo using the following pipeline:

```
  const results = await Price.aggregate([
    { $match: { date: today } },
    { $unwind: '$points' },
    { $match: { 'points.time': { $gte: start, $lte: now } } },
    { $sort: { 'points.time': 1 } },
    { $project: {
      'high': { $max: '$points.price' },
      'low': { $min: '$points.price' },
      'open': { $arrayElemAt: ['$points', 0] },
      'close': { $arrayElemAt: ['$points', -1] }
    } }
  ])
```

However the `$arrayElemAt` operator isn't working preseumably because one of the preceding stages (`$unwind` I believe) converts the array of points I have in my documents to an object. How can I fix this?

Example document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c93ac3ab89045027259a23f"),
    "date" : ISODate("2019-03-21T00:00:00Z"),
    "symbol" : "CC6P",
    "points" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c93ac3ab89045027259a244"),
            "volume" : 553,
            "time" : ISODate("2019-03-21T09:35:34.239Z"),
            "price" : 71
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c93ac3ab89045027259a243"),
            "volume" : 1736,
            "time" : ISODate("2019-03-21T09:57:34.239Z"),
            "price" : 49
        },
      ....
    ],
```

My expected result is an array of objects where the points that should be passed to the project stage should be points in the specified range in the second `$match`. I tried combining the two `$match` stages and removing the `$unwind` stage and the error is gone however the time range isn't being applied

Comment: You have `$unwind`ed the `points` array in the second stage. Can't say until you don't show some of the sample documents and the result you expect.

Comment: @anthonywinzlet Edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing a [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to rollback your `points` array

```
const results = await Price.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "date": today } },
  { "$unwind": "$points" },
  { "$match": { "points.time": { "$gte": start, "$lte": now } } },
  { "$sort": { "points.time": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "points": { "$push": "$points" },
    "date": { "$first": "$date" },
    "symbol": { "$first": "$symbol" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "high": { "$max": "$points.price" },
    "low": { "$min": "$points.price" },
    "open": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$points", 0] },
    "close": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$points", -1] }
  }}
])
```

Comment: The only reason I did the unwind in the first place was to do the second match. Can I avoid the first and second match stages together somehow? Also you're missing two commas in the group stage.

Comment: This works fine btw, I'm just wondering if theres a better way to do this because its going to be executed on a massive amount of data.

Comment: Yes it can be done without using `$unwind`. Pls wait I am editing my answer

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: You removed the sort stage?

Comment: Ohhh... I didn't see the `$sort` stage. You have to use `$unwind` if you want to `$sort` the nested array.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for trying anyway.